# MVC 4, choose dynamically MapRoute on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, url, maproute

I googled a lot but still got no luck.

This is my `RouteConfig.cs`.

```
routes.MapRoute("BackRoute", "back/{controller}/{action}"
     ,new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}"
     ,new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

As you see,There is the same parameter but I've business logic to choose between `BackRoute` and `Default` from code behind.

Can I change route from `ActionFilterAttribute` ?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
   bool logic = true;
   RouteValueDictionary rvd = filterContext.RouteData.Values;
   if(logic){
       filterContext = new RedirectToRouteResult("BackRoute", 
                       new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
                             controller = rvd["controller"].ToString() 
                           , action = rvd["action"].ToString() }));
   }
}
```

Can you guys suggest me the good way to achieve this goal ?

Thank you in advance,

Peace

Comment: This makes me question your design.  What is the purpose of the "back" route?

Comment: saperate between desktop and mobile site. 
my client need desktop URL site look like abc.com/controller/action 
but abc.com/back/controller/action for mobile

Comment: have you looked at using a responsive framework like http://foundation.zurb.com/ or http://getbootstrap.com/?  You wouldn't need this odd specialized routing and might be a better experience for your clients.  Especially with deep linking from search results.

Comment: @mckeejm ; Thanks for information. I'll research on them.

Comment: np, not trying to derail the thread or avert your real question.  Hope those will be useful for you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attribute you can use:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("BackRoute",
     new RouteValueDictionary(
               new { action = "Index", controller = "Home" });
```

UPDATE:
Infinite loop means that you are redirecting to action called in first place.
Try to add one more check before setting RedirectToRouteResult:

```
if(logic && filterContext.RouteData.Route != RouteTable.Routes["BackRoute"])
{
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("BackRoute", 
                                new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
                                     controller = rvd["controller"].ToString() 
                                     , action = rvd["action"].ToString() }));
}
```

Comment: I got Redirect Loop instead. I'll update attribute in the 1st post.

Thanks anyway